# Zend Server 6 with OSX 10.8.2 ... issues with PHPUnit

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, zend-server, zend-server-installation

I really like ZS6, but I'm having issues with PEAR and PHPUnit on OSX 10.8.x.

After ZS6 installation to default paths, PEAR seems to working fine from the command line, however, for some strange reason it installs the phpunit package in a pear folder with a bin, docs, and share folder at /Users/myusername/pear location. That in itself doesn't make sense to me at all. Further, PHPUnit isn't setup to be run from the terminal (command not found).

If you run 'pear list' pear says there are no extensions installed from channel pear.php.net.

my .bash_profile has the following:
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/bin:/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/zend/lib

the php.ini file is still setup as the default locations:
.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear

So far I've tried changing the php.ini path, I've tried changing the .bash_profile export path, I'm tried uninstalling and removing all traces I could find of pear and reinstalling ZS6, and even installing pear manually again... I have the same issue each time.

Is it possible there's a conflict with previous settings on this box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust those config values with pear config-set, for example

```
$ pear config-set php_dir /usr/share/pear/php
$ pear config-set data_dir /usr/share/pear/data
```

Do that for all config values with "broken" paths.

After that, either manually move the files from the old to the new directories, or reinstall all packages.